# DOTNET1011: Framework not installed: .NETFramework

Tags: .net, build, dnx, .net-framework-version, dotnet-cli

I'm adding this here because it caused me a headache this morning while fixing our build server:

Executing `dotnet build` would show me the following errors:

```
DOTNET1011: Framework not installed: .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1
error NU1001: The dependency mscorlib could not be resolved.
```

The error is confusing, as I DO have the .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 installed.

Answer (score 14):

It turns out that I needed the following developer pack (targeting pack):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978

Comment: That is so non-obvious from the error message, thank you for documenting this!